# Client connect timeout on local LAN Fedora 21 server for Minecraft server

Tags: fedora, minecraft

I have a Fedora 21 server running on a local private LAN.  I have setup a minecraft server.  It is running on port 25565 and running the server produces no errors.  My problem is that I cannot get the client to connect to it.  The client connects fine to minecraft servers outside of the local private LAN and when I tested minecraft server on an Ubuntu desktop, the windows machine was able to connect to that server.  So, it seems isolated to the Fedora 21 machine.  It is running as a server, so no GUI!  I have performed a netstat -a on it and see that it states that it is listening to port 25565.  I have turned off firewalld ('sudo systemctl stop firewalld' and then 'sudo systemctl disable firewalld' just to be sure) to see if that was blocking it.  I was still not able to connect.  I can provide other information as needed.  Oh, I am also using Java 1.8u25 and minecraft_server.1.8.1.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem.  Apparently the change requires a server reboot.  Perhaps just restarting the service may also take care of the issue but definitely rebooting the server cleared the problem.

EDIT: I have found that using iptables will open the firewall to allow the game to connect.  I only stated that turning off firewalld allows the game to operate after saving iptables and restarting firewalld.

This should work (let me know if it doesn't):

Be sure to place this before any REJECT statements in the iptables.
You can use `iptables -L --line-numbers | less` to display the table.  I pipe it out to "less" because the table can be quite long and this way one can easily scroll through the information.

```
iptables -I INPUT ## -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT ## -p udp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
iptables-save
```

To do a restart of the firewalld type `sudo systemctl restart firewalld`.

Also keep in mind that this is for the default port in `server.properties` file.  Obviously if the default port is changed in this file, then so would the iptables setting.

Hopefully this will help anyone who may run into this same problem.